# Seeding many to many relations with Prisma

Tags: java, mysql, many-to-many, serverless

I have a Prisma schema that contains Post and Tag tables which are many-to-many relations:
schema.prisma:

```
model Post {
  title          String    @unique
  slug           String    @id /// Slug is an uri safe string derived from the title.
  description    String /// Description for SEO of this post.
  body           String    @db.Text /// The main content of the post.
  tagList        Tag[] /// List of tags associated with this post.
  author         User      @relation("Author", fields: [authorUsername], references: [username], onDelete: Cascade) /// User that is the author of this post.
  authorUsername String /// Username of the author of this post.
  ...
  createdAt      DateTime  @default(now())

  @@index([authorUsername])
}

model Tag {
  tagName String @id
  post    Post[] /// List of posts that have this tag.
}
```

I am using thefaker library to mock up the seed data and tried to use the connect to map the many-to-many relation but it did not work. I am using TiDB Serverless which is MySQL 5.7 compatible but the seeded data did not show the relations have been created.
seed.ts :
...

```
// Create a list of tags to be used in the post
const tags = [...Array(8)].map(() => ({
  tagName: faker.lorem.word(),
}))

// Create a list of posts
const posts = [...Array(10)].map(async () => {
  const title = faker.lorem.words({ min: 2, max: 5 })
  const author = await _.sample(users)

  return {
    title,
    slug: faker.helpers.slugify(title),
    description: faker.lorem.sentence(),
    body: faker.lorem.paragraphs({ min: 2, max: 5 }),
    authorUsername: author.username,
  }
})

async function main() {
  // Delete all data
  ...
  await prisma.tag.deleteMany()
  console.log('Deleted records in Tag table')

  await prisma.post.deleteMany()
  console.log('Deleted records in Post table')

  ...

  // Create tags
  await prisma.tag.createMany({
    data: tags,
  })
  console.log('Added Tag data')

  // Create posts
  posts.map(async post => {
    const tagList = await _.sampleSize(tags, _.random(1, 3))
    await prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        ...(await post),
        tagList: {
          connect: tagList,
        },
      },
    })
  })
  console.log('Added Post data')
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect()
  })
  .catch(async e => {
    console.error(e)
    await prisma.$disconnect()
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

What's the proper way to map them in the seed or do I have to modify my schema for this?